# HTML 5 video autoplay not work in iphone

Tags: iphone

I created a website for preview of HTML5 video autoplay, but it is not working on iPhone

Can anyone please let me know how can i make it work?

Comment: auto play is by default disabled on mobile device

Comment: Also if possible don't use autoplay in general, it usually just makes the user annoyed by your product.

Answer (score 0):

You can find more information about under which conditions iOS will allow autoplay here: https://webkit.org/blog/6784/new-video-policies-for-ios/.

As far as I understand you are only allowed to autoplay if your video is muted or doesn't have a audio track in general (so basically a "modern gif").